# StretchBlt a bitmap without overwriting what's already drawn at the destination

Tags: winapi, bitmap

I have a drawing application that draws many lines, polygons etc. on a device context. I'm also drawing background bitmaps that come from an external source and take a long time to load.

When drawing a new frame I first start threads that load the bitmaps, then draw my vector data, and at the end would like to draw the loaded bitmaps while preserving the vector data. I need the bitmaps "under" the vector data but I can't draw them first because they're not loaded, and waiting for them to load would slow things down a lot.

My idea was to apply the "bitmap with transparency" technique:

1. Copy the portion of my device context that would be covered by
   the bitmap into a monochrome image, anything drawn with the
   background color should be drawn on, everything else is off-limits.
2. Copy the image over the bitmap (with the proper ROP code) to mark
   what needs to be transparent in the bitmap
3. StretchBlt the modified bitmap onto the device context

The bitmap needs to be transformed to fit properly on my device context, so I use `SetWorldTransform` to apply an affine transformation to my device context. The transformation has both a rotation and a shear.

Unfortunately, this fails at step 1 because, as per the documentation of [`StretchBlt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt):

> If the source transformation has a rotation or shear, an error occurs.

Now, I did try setting the inverse transformation on my monochrome DC, which would transform my sheared data into a proper rectangle, but the function still fails.

So I guess my question is: how do I bitblit a raster image without deleting my data (a function where I give a transparent color in the *destination*, not the *source*, would be perfect), OR is there an easy way to extract the color data from a device context that has a rotate and shear transform on it?

Comment: Try the `AlphaBlend()` function instead.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I still need to know which pixels to make transparent on the bitmap. I don't see how `AlphaBlend()` would help.

Comment: You could do it the other way around. Draw the vector data into a bitmap that has an alpha channel. Use `AlphaBlend()` to combine this image with the background image. Note that GDI doesn't respect the alpha channel, so you would have to use GDI+ or Direct2D to draw the vector data.

Comment: After drawing your bitmap, draw your vector graphics again?

Comment: @PaulSanders drawing the vector data is also slow (too many objects). That's why it makes sense to do these in parallel. For now I copy my vector data to a bitmap at the end of the drawing, blit all my bitmaps to a separate bitmap the size of the DC, `TransparentBlt` the bitmap with the vector data over it, and then finally blit the result on the original device context. This avoids the transformations because it's applied to the entire device context.